# How do I play background music in my iPhone game?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone/iPad - Loop Background Music?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631353/iphone-ipad-loop-background-music)

The official iphone docs aren't bad, but I'm finding them pretty unhelpful on this subject - all I can find is an API for playing midi files, but that's not what I want. I just want to play an MP3 in the background.
And if the user is already playing their own music, obviously I don't want to play my own on top of it.

Is there a "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The CrashLanding demo app in the SDK has a SoundEngine class that can play background music.