# playing background audio on iphone

Tags: iphone, audio

How can I play a background audio while my application is running?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183112/how-do-i-play-background-music-in-my-iphone-game

Answer (score 9):

Okay.  This is a solution for background sound on iOS4 & iOS5 (definitely works up to iOS 5.0.1), and I have tested it only with AVPlayer.  It should probably work for MPMusicPlayerController too.

Required frameworks:

- `AVFoundation.framework`
- `AudioToolbox.framework`

In your `Info.plist`, for the key `UIBackgroundModes`, add `audio`.

In `MyAppDelegate.h`:

- reference `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` & `<AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`
- implement the protocol `AVAudioSessionDelegate`:

  ```
  @interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, AVAudioSessionDelegate>
  ```
- define a method `ensureAudio`:

  ```
  // Ensures the audio routes are setup correctly
  - (BOOL) ensureAudio;
  ```

In `MyAppDelegate.m`:

- implement the `ensureAudio` method:

  ```
  - (BOOL) ensureAudio
  {
      // Registers this class as the delegate of the audio session (to get background sound)
      [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];  

      // Set category
      NSError *categoryError = nil;
      if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&categoryError]) {
          NSLog(@"Audio session category could not be set"); 
          return NO;
      }

      // Activate session
      NSError *activationError = nil;
      if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError]) {
          NSLog(@"Audio session could not be activated");
          return NO;
      }

      // Allow the audio to mix with other apps (necessary for background sound)
      UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
      AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);

      return YES;
  }
  ```
- in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, before you assign the root view controller, run `[self ensureAudio]`:

  ```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
      // Configure audio session
      [self ensureAudio];

      // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
      self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

      return YES;
  }
  ```
- implement the `AVAudioSessionDelegate` methods like this:

  ```
  #pragma mark - AVAudioSessionDelegate

  - (void) beginInterruption
  {

  }

  - (void) endInterruption
  {
      // Sometimes the audio session will be reset/stopped by an interruption
      [self ensureAudio];
  }

  - (void) inputIsAvailableChanged:(BOOL)isInputAvailable
  {

  }
  ```
- ensure that your app continues to run in the background.  You can use the ol' `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler]` if you want, but I think there are better ways.
- play the actual audio (note I'm using ARC, that's why there are no `release` calls):

  ```
  NSURL * file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"beep" withExtension:@"aif"];    
  AVURLAsset * asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:file options:nil];
  AVPlayerItem * item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
  __block AVPlayer * player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:item];
  __block id finishObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification 
                                                                        object:player.currentItem 
                                                                         queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                                                                    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:finishObserver];

      // Reference the 'player' variable so ARC doesn't release it until it's
      // finished playing.
      player = nil;
  }];

  // Trigger asynchronous load
  [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tracks"] completionHandler:^{
      // Start playing the beep (watch out - we're not on the main thread here)!
      [player play];
   }];
  ```
- And it shooooooooooooould work!

Comment: If you are using MPMusicPlayerController to actually play the music, be sure to use [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer], and not to use [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer]. Also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507541/avaudioplayer-turns-off-ipod-how-to-work-around which will show you what to do if you don't want your app to stop whatever music was playing when the user starts your app

Comment: Test this behavior on a physical device.  It doesn't work in the Simulator for me.  It does work on a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your app also for recording - then don't forget to change setCategory to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord. In other case you won't be able to record

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&setCategoryErr];
```