# AVAudioPlayer turns off iPod - how to work around?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I use AVAudioPlayer to play sounds in my app, but it turns off the iPod when a sound plays.

Is there a way to prevent this? I don't want to use System Sounds because I can't control their volume.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work for you (taken from my Ambiance app)

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
UInt32 doSetProperty = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(doSetProperty), &doSetProperty);
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

From the docs:

> kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers
>   Changes the mixing behavior of the
>   kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback
>   and
>   kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord
>   audio session categories. Setting this
>   property to TRUE (any nonzero value)
>   allows mixing of iPod audio with
>   application audio. Other aspects of
>   these categories, such as their
>   Ring/Silent switch behavior, are not
>   affected.
>
> This property has value of FALSE (0)
>   by default. When the audio session
>   category changes, such as during an
>   interruption, the value of this
>   property reverts to FALSE. To regain
>   mixing behavior you must then re-set
>   this property.
>
> Always check to see if setting this
>   property succeeds or fails, and react
>   appropriately; behavior may change in
>   future releases of iPhone OS.
>
> Available in iPhone OS 3.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AudioServices.h.

Comment: Put this in the app delegate. Worked fine for me. Have fun, fellow googlers ;)

Comment: Tremendous! Thanks! For other beginners like me: to get this to link you need to do #import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
and to link the AudioToolbox framework. For help on how to do that in XCode 4.2, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4

Comment: Is this still the best way to accomplish this in iOS 7?

Comment: @MattLoszak I would ask this in the devforums as iOS 7 is under NDA

Comment: It's deprecated since iOS7

Comment: For those looking for workarounds: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers)

Comment: since iOS7:

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];`