# AVAudioPlayer cannot play on background when Youtube playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I make an alarm feature for my app, at the time I setup for alarm fire I can play a music track with `AVAudioPlayer`, it worked well on background mode. But if at this time I opening Youtube app and playing a video then the `AVAudioPlayer` not work.

Please tell me why this happen and how to resolve this issue, how to play both at the same time

This is code I implement:

```
NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"remind2"
                                          withExtension:@"mp3"];
avSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
            initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];
[avSound setDelegate:self];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

[avSound prepareToPlay];
[avSound setNumberOfLoops:10];
[avSound setVolume:1.0];
[avSound play];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

by this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];
```

and I resolved my problem

It takes me two days to put the right questions to this problem, I only find the solution when i ask Google why Youtube stop my audio stream and this result search help me

[AVAudioPlayer turns off iPod - how to work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507541/avaudioplayer-turns-off-ipod-how-to-work-around)

Answer (score 0):

This is happened because of Youtube app also set property **"UIBackgroundMode"** property in plist. And even if you check any of other Music app like gaana, savan, etc. this will happened in all of the music app.

Comment: I don't think so, Youtube app on my iPad not playing on background Mode, it stop immediately when i push home button

Comment: Same thing happened in iPhone also? @nghien_rbc

Comment: Yes, I've tested with iOS 9.3 on iPhone 4S and get the same result