# how to play MID sound file in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have implement game application in which i want to play mid sound file in the background.How it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183112/how-do-i-play-background-music-in-my-iphone-game

Comment: @Oren Mazor: In the question you linked, the poster is asking how to play mp3 files. In this question, the poster wants to know how to play midi files. It's a totally different question.

Comment: @Asaph, I think the answer for the question I linked answers this question as well.

Comment: @Oren Mazor: No it doesn't. Midi is not at all like other audio formats such as mp3. It's a totally different animal requiring a different API.

Comment: This question is closer to the one he's asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449057/midi-player-synthesizer-library-for-the-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is there is no easy way.  When this question came up [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449057/midi-player-synthesizer-library-for-the-iphone) the best recommendation was to try porting [TiMidity++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449057/midi-player-synthesizer-library-for-the-iphone).  This appears to be [difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083631/timidity-need-help-compiling-this-library-for-the-iphone).
A more iPhoney solution would be to convert your midi file into an audio file using something such as 
[Easy-Pro Midi to Audio Converter 1.3](http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Multimedia_and_Graphics/Misc__Sound_Tools/Easy_Pro_Midi_to_Audio_Converter.html)
 and then playing the the audio file normally in your app.  This may have the downside of enlarging your app size.