# Loop background music?

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, audio

1. What's the best way of playing background music for my iOS game? And how do I do this?
2. What's the best format of having that music file in for playback?
3. Will this this song happily play through the entire game, no interruptions when changing view?
4. How can I loop this music?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mySound" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite

[player play];
```

and you can jump through by setting the `currentTime`:

```
player.currentTime = 10; //jump to 10th second
```

Comment: Don't forget about adding the `AudioToolbox` and `AVFoundation` frameworks to your project, and importing `<AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>` and `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` in your view controller delegate file.

Comment: Traditionally I’d found that MP3 files don’t loop well — is that no longer the case?

Comment: @Hithere - you don't need to add `AudioToolbox`, that is a different Framework. Also @DavidDunham - yes, AAC files are supposed to be better than MP3s for looping.

Comment: Just a comment, the AVAudioPlayer must be an attribute of the class that will play the music. It cannot be defined inside a method.

Comment: But you can put the Audio Player inside a different class and use that class to play music.