# Playing continuos sound in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, audio, ios, core-audio

I have an iPhone application which requires me to play a looping mp3 sound during the entire lifetime of app.

But based on some actions performed by user this mp3 should stop/pause for while & another mp3 should play & then this mp3 should resume playing again.

I havent really used any audio API on iPhone yet, I've just used AudioToolbox for playing sounds on button taps thats all.

So what do you guys recommend I should do. 
Any pointers...? suggestions....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just as I wrote in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631353/iphone-ipad-loop-background-music/4570522#4570522), you can use `AVAudioPlayer`

code extract:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mySound" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL URLForString:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL];
player.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite

[player play];
```

and you can pause it with:

```
[player pause];
```

Comment: yes I did found this solution after googling a bit more.. Nonetheless thanks forr your reply