# Play and stop sound (2 views)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, audio

How can I play sound from abutton in my 1st view then stop it from another view (with abutton)

Comment: Of course not but I've searched for it a lot but I can't find the code I want

Comment: @user1346627 well, if you go to Google and past **"How can I play sound from abutton in my 1st view then stop it from another view (with abutton)"** I am sure you won't find much thing...

Answer (score 1):

First make clear that you want to stop sound from other view not view controller.

If you want to stop from other view then make audio player your class object and in other view's button method stop it.

If you want to stop from other view controller then use delegation.

Answer (score 1):

Easy Peasy! First of all add the AVFoundation framework and implement the AVAudioPlayer. You can check the documentation and other stack overflow questions on how to play music/sound. Then make that AVAudioPlayer a property in one class. Then declare a method that stops the sound, by calling `[audioPlayer stop]` also worth mentioning that `[audioPlayer pause] // and [audioPlayer play]` both exist too. Or, you could call these messages through the other class' pointer to this class itself. Then in the other class, declare an IBAction that has a pointer to the other class and send a message to that class telling it to perform the stop method. Simple, this is a structure:

1. In FirstView, declare an AVAudioPlayer property that plays music
2. In FirstView, declare a stop method
3. Implement that stop method
4. Declare and draw a UIButton with an IBAction method that changes page to SecondView
5. In SecondView `viewDidLoad` method, add and draw a UIButton that links to an IBAction that calls the stop method OR just goes calls `[FirstView audioPlayer] stop];` or something similar!

REMEMBER TO CONFORM TO DELEGATE! IMPORTANT!

SUGGESTED QUESTION YOU CAN REFER TO FOR THE AVAUDIOPLAYER CODE!

[iPhone/iPad - Loop Background Music?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631353/iphone-ipad-loop-background-music)

But remember do not literally copy this code, remember the properties and you obviously have parameter modifications. Sorry if Im sounding too obvious its just that your question was so vague I couldn't tell if you were a total beginner or not!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your player with a class which listens to custom notifications.
e.g.:

```
#define PlayerPlayNotification @"PlayerPlayNotification"
#define PlayerStopNotification @"PlayerStopNotification"
```

Then each button can send the desired notification in order to start/stop play without knowing about the actual player or having any pointers to it.