# Generate paused/discontinuous beeps in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio

I am creating one sound based application where I need to generate different oscillations for sound wave. One part that I need to achieve in this is the discontinuous or paused beep. I am trying to do this using I'm doing variations in the sine wave using Core Audio, but I'm not getting the desired output.

Basically I need to generate variable sound oscillation patterns like Dog Whistler app.

Can anyone help me in proper direction for this

Comment: you say "I'm not getting the desired output". What is the desired output and what are you getting? eg are you getting undesired clicks? are the frequencies wrong, etc. Please be as specific as possible and I'll be more likely to help.

Comment: Reference app for this is Dog Whistler App where we need to generate different Sound patterns

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4570522/207616) how to loop background music. You can create an audio file with 0.5 sec beep and 1 sec silence and loop that file infinitely via `AVAudioPlayer`. As well as pausing the beep sequence via `[player pause];`

This will work if you have some predefined beep intervals/oscillations but not if you need 100% user customization. You can also look for sound effects to adjust the pitch and frequency.

Comment: My sound needs to have frequency change at runtime and also needs to have variable sound oscillation patterns like dog whistler app/