# Loop background music in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, sprite-kit

I'm finishing a game for iOS done with the SpriteKit framework. I want to know if there is any way to loop background music while the user is playing. SpriteKit includes a simple music player but it does not allow looping music... So I want to know how could I accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: pretty much this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4570522/2054786

Comment: hmm... what about [SKAction repeatForever:] and playAction?

Comment: You should post the code you currently have above. `repeatForever` should work just fine. Are you preloading the audio ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `AVAudioPlayer` for this purpose:

In your .h:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

and add the following to `interface`

```
AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

In .m, initialize player with audio oath url:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                             pathForResource:@"bg_music"
                                             ofType:@"mp3"]];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = -1;
```

and when you need to play the audio, you can call:

```
[player play];
```

**Note:** 
"numberOfLoops" is the number of times that the sound will return to the beginning upon reaching the end.

- A value of zero means to play the sound just once.
- A value of one will result in playing the sound twice, and so on...
- Any negative number will loop indefinitely until stopped.

Keep Coding................ :)

Comment: This is the right answer.  Apple's doc even says to do this for background music: https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417664-playsoundfilenamed

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather use SKAction:

```
[SKAction repeatForever:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"hello.caf" waitForCompletion:YES]];
```

or:

```
[SKAction repeatAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"hello.caf" waitForCompletion:YES]
                 count:100];
```

More info at [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/playSoundFileNamed%3awaitForCompletion%3a).

Comment: If I put nil it says: "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion". If I put YES, music does not seem to loop and if I put no, music starts constantly... My music file is in .m4a is that a problem?

Comment: @Bytes, just send YES to wait param there instead of nil. About supported formats - cannot tell you, see Apple Docs. Should work just fine, saw an example of this in WWDC presentations for SpriteKit.

Comment: I get ``No know class method for selector 'repeatForever'`` error in XCode.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, maybe what you mean is `repeatActionForever`?

Comment: Actually my code `[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"outer_space_rumble_lp_01.wav" waitForCompletion:YES]];` doesn't play the audio... I've tried placing in different files/methods, but no luck. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Run the action with `[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"outer_space_rumble_lp_01.wav" waitForCompletion:YES]]];`

Comment: [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"background.wav" waitForCompletion:YES]];

Comment: SKAction is great for a cheeky little sound effect but for but for background music AVAudioPlayer is always preferable. Why? you can if your phone has an existing audio function playing music you can silence the game music. Much better UI. Sure there are ways to do this to SKActions but very Messy

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in two ways.

First:

1) `@import AVFoundation;` //Import this in AppDelegate file

2) `@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer * backgroundMusicPlayer;` //Define a property in AppDelegate file

3) under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate method in AppDelegate file wrote below code

```
NSError *error;
    NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"bg" withExtension:@"wav"];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

4) Now you can use backgroundMusicPlayer property in any class like below code

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
```

Second:

If you want to use SKAction Use below code

```
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:10.0];
        SKAction *performSelector = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(playEffectBgSounds) onTarget:self];
        SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[performSelector, wait]];
        SKAction *repeat   = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];
        [self runAction:repeat];

-(void)playEffectBgSounds{

    //Play Sound
    [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"chick.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];

}
```

Comment: This is one of the situations where I find a dedicated AudioPlayer Singleton a cleaner solution than using AppDelegate. In most games you'll only hear once song at a time.

Answer (score 1):

In your scene class add:

Method 1:

```
self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("music.mp3", waitForCompletion: true)))
```

Method 2:

```
self.addChild(SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "music.mp3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AVAudioPlayer *myplayer = ...
[myplayer setNumberOfLoops: INFINITY];
```